# Mixin's names parameterization with template argument

Tags: d, mixins, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to generate a name for a function within a mixin template? Something like this:

```
mixin template Generator(string name)
{
    @property void mixin(name) pure nothrow // mixin(name) is not valid :(
    { 
            //some cool stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that I can do the stuff with mixin, but there is no code highlighting for the D in strings and it is hard to debug such code.

Comment: You might want to try the `q{ code here }` style of string. They are often highlighted, though it doesn't help much with the debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm hoping somebody can come up with something cleaner, but this *should* do what you want:

```
mixin template Generator(string name)
{
    mixin("alias " ~ name ~ " = _fun;");
    @property void _fun pure nothrow
    { 
        //some cool stuff here
    }
}
```

This unfortunately injects `_fun` into the local namespace as well, though if you use `Generator` more than once any calls to `_fun` will be rejected as ambiguous. This could be a problem if you legitimately have a function named `_fun` defined elsewhere.

Although you are generating multiple `_funs`, the calls placed through the aliases created by `Generator` are not ambiguous as they refer to `_fun` scoped by a specific template instantiation:

```
mixin Generator!"foo";
mixin Generator!"bar";

foo();  // not ambiguous, calls Generator!"foo"._fun
bar();  // not ambiguous, calls Generator!"bar"._fun
_fun(); // ambiguous, rejected by compiler
```

EDIT: Just wanted to throw out another crazy idea I had:

```
mixin template Generator(names ...) {
  @property void opDispatch(string s)() pure nothrow {
    foreach(name ; names) {
      static if (s == name) {
        // do stuff
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Foo {
  mixin Generator!("hello", "goodbye");
}

void main() {
  Foo foo;

  foo.hello;
  foo.goodbye;
}
```

This avoids generating a garbage `_fun`, but it does require that your class doesn't already define `opDispatch`. Furthermore, it can't be used multiple times in the same class (you can't overload the same method from different mixin templates in the same scope), you have to call it once and pass in all your names as args. This might be preferable, however, if you'd like to send in all the names in one go and don't already define `opDispatch`.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. But I forget to mention that use case is to use such "Generator" multiple times with different names. Anyway, your solution is useful for other tasks =)

Comment: Please edit accordingly your question, that's too relevant ;-)

Comment: @DenisGladkiy, `Generator` can be used with multiple names, see edit above. I was actually a little surprised that this worked :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace to do some string trickery at compile time to hide the horrible concatenations:

```
mixin(replace(q{ 
    @property void mixin(name) pure nothrow 
    { 
            //some cool stuff here
    }

}, q{mixin(name)}, name));
```